# Cannot see adb logs of android wear app on Android Studio Logcat

Tags: android, wear-os, android-bluetooth, android-logcat, android-studio-2.0

I'm able to connect my moto 360 device through Android Wear app on my phone.
I've followed [Debugging over Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) article and used below commands to connect wearable.

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub

adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444
```

and everything works fine, but when I try to run my app, locat shows an error as soons as App gets installed on wearable.

**I've tried to use other available port numbers  but no luck**. Here is the error I see on logcat. Let me know if I'm missing anything here.

Thanks in advance.

```
 E/fd: IO Error creating local socket at com.sample.wearapp
                                 java.io.IOException: Address already in use
                                     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bindLocal(Native Method)
                                     at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bind(LocalSocketImpl.java:306)
                                     at android.net.LocalServerSocket.<init>(LocalServerSocket.java:48)
                                     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.<init>(Server.java:82)
                                     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.create(Server.java:76)
                                     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:290)
                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4712)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: that wear companion app is very buggy afaik.

Comment: Does your app work if you install your app by packaging it with a mobile app? Does your app work on an emulator?